# Jest Test Implementation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lwc-jest

Hi I need to mock the scenario as below but getting stuck as data is not getting pulled from the JSON

```
testDataJSon
{
    "testpos":[
        {
            "test1": false,
            "test2":true
        }

    ],
    "testNeg":[
        {
            "test3": true,
            "test4":false
        }
    ],

}



    it('Positive test for the testDataJson', async()=>{
        await flushPromises();
        const dataP = testDataJSon.testpos.test1;
        const daatPS =testDataJSon.testpos.test2;
        expect(dataP).toBe(false);
        expect(daatPS).toBe(true);
    });




error i am facing Expected: false
                  Received: undefined
```

can anyone help me out how to fetch the data in the daatP from JSON as it is currently showing undefined.

```
error i am facing Expected: false
                  Received: undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your JSON object, you should be grabbing the data as follows:

```
const dataP = testDataJSon.testpos[0].test1;
const daatPS =testDataJSon.testpos[0].test2;
```

This is because `testpos` is an array so you need to grab the first entry of that array before getting the `test1` and `test2` keys.